# php login page with mysql and session

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a login page with `session()` function and I had some problem with the code, but I don't know why.

What I want to do after that is in my admin page I want it to say "welcome (the username that inserted in the form)", but I dont know how.

I tried with `session()` but its shows me:

`PHPSESSID`

What should I do?

This is the code

```
<?php
$sid = $_POST["username"];
session_start(); 
include("../inc/passwords.php"); 
if ($_POST["ac"]=="log") { /// do after login form is submitted  
 if ($USERS[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"]) { /// check if submitted 
      $_SESSION["logged"]=$_POST["username"]; 
 } else { 
      echo 'Incorrect username/password. Please, try again.'; 
 }; 
}; 
if (array_key_exists($_SESSION["logged"],$USERS)) { //// check if user is logged     or     not  
 header('Location: index.php'); //// if user is logged show a message  
} else { //// if not logged show login form 
 echo '<table align="center" border="0">
<h3 style="color: #555" align="center" class="">بالرجاء تسجيل الدخول للمتابعة</h3>
<form action="login.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ac" value="log">
<tr><td>الاســـــــم</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" size="20">    </td></tr>
<tr><td>كلمة السر</td><td>:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" size="20">    </td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input class="buttons" type="submit"     value="تسجيل الدخول"></td></tr>
</form>
</table>'; 
}; 
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it wont work using session with the welcome thing

try by using mysql

like 
when the admin puts it name and password
his name is putted in a table in mysql
and in the index for the admin page
you query the table 
like

```
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 mysql_query(SELECT username FROM admins where username='$username');
```

Comment: i will try to do it now and iwill see what will happens

Comment: Do not use mysql use mysqli it will be removed in the future

Comment: Do not use mysql use mysqli it will be removed in the future @shaikibrahim what do you mean by removed in the future

Comment: @AlmoullimDev. What he means is the official support for `mysql_*` database functions have been depreciated in PHPs' new release of 5.5.. They will start to generate `E_DEPRECIATED` warnings.. This is the first step to remove a library/function from PHP. MySQLi/PDO  offers more functionality and bound parameters for added security.

Comment: so this means when they officially remove mysql all websites which uses php files with mysql will fail immediately. Most probably browser will show "mysqli" errors or just undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Just for knowledge:

Most important things to be remember.

Always start session after php tag starts.

e.g.

```
<?php
session_start();
```

If you start it like:

```
<?php
$sid = $_POST["username"];
session_start();
```

It will through error message : `headers already sent` etc

Comment: Headers will only be sent if there is output above a `session_start` or `header("");` call.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the piece of code:

```
if ($USERS[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"]) { /// check if submitted 
      $_SESSION["logged"]=$_POST["username"]; 
 }
```

You need to make sure the `$_SESSION["logged"]` is actually set. Perhaps try performing an `echo` on it. If it is empty, it would be the logic not evaluating to `true`.

Also make sure you do a `session_start()` on your index.php page.